# How to morphing of two images in iphone programming

Tags: iphone, morphing

how to do morphing of two images in iphone programming.?

Comment: First, can you do a morph on other platforms? I think the theory and algorithms are mostly platform independent (unless the iPhone has special hardware to support morphs, which I doubt).

Answer (score 5):

Your question is not iphone related.. the kind of algorithm you are looking for is language-agnostic since it just work with images.

By the way it's quite complex to morph two images, usually you have to

- embed a grid of points over the two images that links characteristics that should be morphed. For example if you have two faces you would use a grid that connects eyes, the mouth, ears, the nose, the edge of the face and so on: these two grid tells the morpher how to "translate" a point into another one while blending the two images
- the previous step can be done automatically (with specific software) or by hand. more points you place better will be your results
- then you can do the real morphing sequence: basically you do an interpolation between the two images (in which the parameter that you use will decide how much will be the final risult similar to the first or the second image)
- you should also apply some blending effect to actually create a believable result, always using a parametric function according to the morphing position

Comment: These steps looks very logical.
@Jack do you know any API regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIView animation to transition from one UIView to another. This should provide some sort of lame morphing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XMRM, which is written in C++: http://www.cg.tuwien.ac.at/~xmrm/

There is no image morphing API in the iOS SDK.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't an API for it. You'll have to do it yourself.

...ask a short question, get a short answer...