# how to do image morphing as in FatBooth app - iPhone

Tags: iphone

I want to build a similar app as fatbooth and want some ideas on how to do this. I googled for Image morphing in iPhone but didn't find anything. Should I use some server side language to morph Image?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks
Saurabh

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to morphing of two images in iphone programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048732/how-to-morphing-of-two-images-in-iphone-programming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only language you can really use is C# or c++. the maths is very complicated although I am sure you can get a book or two that cover image manipulation.
I don't know if there is an open source morphing framework, but that is your best option - it doesn't have to be specific to the iPhone, but the integration will be hard.

I don't know what you mean about server side, unless there is a server you know of that does it and you want a wrapper around it

Comment: by using server side i mean that I'll send the image to server and use some server side language to manipulate it (like PHP or C#) and then download it back to iPhone for user viewing...

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to use Obj-C/C?

Comment: @kubi can you please provide some image morphing obj-C/C code or give any link for this..

Comment: Do you know of a server that does image morphing that you are going to use? Certainly nothing in PHP.

Comment: @Sourabh No, sorry. I don't know of any image morphing software.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, take a look at displacement mapping: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/mapping/

Basically, you use grayscale images to bloat/shrink/squeeze/etc parts of a person's face. I made an app called FaceCraze which had to implement a poor man's FatBooth as part of the face transformation, and I used grayscale images very similar to the examples in http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/mapping/#spherical

edit: You can use the ImageMagick library in your iOS apps too: [Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#iOS)