# How do image distortion applications like the 'Booth' series work?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, image-processing

I just wanted to know how all of the iPhone/iPad 'Booth' applications (i.e FatBooth, BaldBooth, SkinnyBooth) work.  How do they do their image distortion?

Comment: On iPad it is magic. Not sure about the iPhone

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do iPhone applications that change your photo work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181649/how-do-iphone-applications-that-change-your-photo-work)

Comment: Another related question is [how to do image morphing as in FatBooth app - iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708442/how-to-do-image-morphing-as-in-fatbooth-app-iphone).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's image processing.

First you need to find the face of the person.

Then you process the face with an algorithm or a layer to add effects.

You should take a look at OpenCV framework ( http://opencv.org/ ) for face recognition (and opencv forums to get ideas ^^).

Good luck.