# 2D distortion of a face from an image on iOS? (similar to Fat Booth etc.)

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es

I was just wondering if someone knows about some good library or tutorial on how to achieve a 2D distortion of a face taken from an image taken by the user.

I would like to achieve a similar effect to the one in Fatify, Oldify, all those Fat Booths, etc., because I am creating an app where you will throw something at the face and I would the face to jiggle and move when the object hits it.

How should I do this?

Comment: Well, 3D is probably not what you are looking for.  Its probably more along the lines of 2D distortion.  Extrapolating 3D from a 2D image is extremely advanced and technical.

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing that out. I'll try to change the title :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found an almost identical question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330410/how-do-image-distortion-applications-like-the-booth-series-work) with an accepted answer.

Also, speaking about distorsion algorithms there is an algorithm used by GIMP called "liquid rescale". You can find it [here](http://liquidrescale.wikidot.com/) and is written in C/C++ so you could integrate it in your iOS App (license permitting, I haven't checked that).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225548/resources-for-image-distortion-algorithms) is another similar question as well.

Hope that this helps to get you started on this.

EDIT: [Some examples](http://liquidrescale.wikidot.com/en:examples) (will post some code soon)

EDIT 2: I was looking for some code and I found some blog posts that explain the filtering algorithms used to implement the liquid rescale algorithm. Is not easy and I don't think in short time and with no prior knowledge on the subject I could do more than sharing this [link](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#liquid-rescale). The author of the GIMP implementation appears to be called "Shai Avidan" (see this [post](http://mattiesworld.gotdns.org/weblog/2007/11/06/liquid-rescale-open-source-implementation/)). I suggest you might try to contact him or anyone else in the field (see wikipedia references on the [subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seam_carving)). Sorry if I can't help more.

EDIT 3: I found a book with some JAVA code on "[Principles of Digital Image Processing: Fundamental Techniques](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/1848001908/ref=rdr_ext_tmb)".

Also, [this](http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee368/) is a link to a Digital Image Processing course by Prof. Bernd Girod at Standford University. There are slides and tutorials.

Then I found some more results by googling the term "Principles of Digital Image Processing spring".

Anyway.. this was just to add some extra to the answer as I was thinking about it before.

Comment: Hey thanks, I wasn't probably searching enough :)) Although, could you post some example? I would be very happy if you could :))

Comment: Will look for some code in few minutes and update the answer: liquidrescale.wikidot.com/en:examples

Comment: @DominikHadl I just added an EDIT

Comment: Hey, thanks really much for that! I will do my best to make it work :))

Comment: Wellcome, I just tried to look for some university tutorials.. sometimes they are publicly available. Haven't had much luck ..

Comment: @DominikHadl hej, I added an EDIT 3 with some general material I found online. Hope that helps.