# How can I achieve image morphing in iOS?

Tags: ios, api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to morphing of two images in iphone programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048732/how-to-morphing-of-two-images-in-iphone-programming)

Is there any API for image morphing in iOS?